# Strange behavior when getting key

Tags: c#, dictionary, asp.net-mvc-5

So I have this line:

```
string theWhereClause = " levels = '" + LevelItems[SelectedLevel] + 
                        "' AND areas = '" + AreaItems[SelectedArea] + "'";
```

The `AreaItems` is a `Dictionary<string,string>` and the `SelectedArea` has the value "Statistics and Probability" for some reason, when debugging, it breaks on this line:

```
AreaItems[SelectedArea]
```

and throws this error:

**The given key was not present in the dictionary.**

This is what is inside the `AreaItems[]`:

```
[0] {[All, All]}
[1] {[Number, Number]}
[2] {[Shape Space and Measures, Shape Space and Measures]}
[3] {[Statistics and Probability, Statistics and Probability]}
[4] {[Algebra, Algebra]}
[5] {[Other, Other]}
```

However, if I hard code the string so:

`AreaItems["Statistics and Probability"]` it works perfectly!

What I have tried:

```
AreaItems[SelectedArea].Trim()
```

Thinking their were some hidden characters, this still didn't work.

I tried:

```
SelectedArea = "Shape Space and Measures";
AreaItems[SelectedArea]
```

Thinking that spacing in the variable would be the reason, I was wrong.. It works with that value in the variable.

I did an IF statement to check if their was any difference between the 2:

```
if(SelectedArea == "Statistics and Probability")
{

}
```

and it falls through the IF statement, so that returns true.

Then lastly something that did work is:

```
string temp = AreaItems[SelectedArea];
string theWhereClause = " levels = '" + LevelItems[SelectedLevel] + 
                        "' AND areas = '" + temp + "'";
```

All I did this time is store the `AreaItems` value in a different string (temp) and placed that string within the `theWhereClause` and it worked!

Although this works, i'm still intrigued as to why the first time it didn't!

What difference is grabbing the value from `AreaItems[SelectedArea]` and `string temp = AreaItems[SelectedArea]` is there to cause such a strange behavior?

**Additional code to help you guys:**

So to call this method I am using `AJAX` which sends the values to this method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SearchForWorksheets(string level, string area)
    {
        Models.FreeMathsWorksheets freeWorkSheets = new Models.FreeMathsWorksheets();
        freeWorkSheets.SelectedLevel = level;

        // When debugging, at this point the area is "Statistics and Probability"
        freeWorkSheets.SelectedArea = area

        freeWorkSheets.BuildWhereClause();
        List<Models.SearchMathWorksheetsList> WorksheetList = new List<Models.SearchMathWorksheetsList>();
        WorksheetList = freeWorkSheets.ConvertDataTableToList();
        return Json(WorksheetList);
     }
```

Now because of this line `Models.FreeMathsWorksheets freeWorkSheets = new Models.FreeMathsWorksheets();` the constructor which calls methods to build the dictionarys gets called within the `FreeMathsWorksheets` class:

```
public class FreeMathsWorksheets
{      

   public string SelectedLevel { get; set; }

   public string SelectedArea { get; set; }

    public FreeMathsWorksheets()
    {
        PopulateAreaDropdown();
    }

    public void PopulateAreaDropdown()
    {
        string theSql = "SELECT * FROM HL_FreeWorksheetAreas";
        IDataAccess da = new DataAccess();
        DataTable dt = da.GetData(theSql);
        AreaItems = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        // Default add an all value
        AreaItems.Add("All", "All");

        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            AreaItems.Add(row["area"].ToString(), row["area"].ToString());
        }
    }    

    public void BuildWhereClause()
    {
        string theWhereClause = " levels = '" + LevelItems[SelectedLevel] + "' AND areas = '" + AreaItems[SelectedArea] + "'";
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe trying to add [ContainsKeys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw5aaea4.aspx), see what it returns.

Comment: `AreaItems[SelectedArea].Trim()` you're trimming *after* you've accessed the dictionary, don't you mean `AreaItems[SelectedArea.Trim()]`, also if you break on that line, what's the debugger saying for `SelectedArea`?

Comment: It doesn't seem like you need a dictionary if the keys and values are the same.

Comment: @juharr I understand, I should of mentioned that for now just for testing i'm setting the string for both key and value

Comment: `String trimmed = SelectedArea.Substring(SelectedArea.Trim().Length)` To get the trimmed string.

Comment: @Lloyd I spoke too soon, having replaced `AreaItems[SelectedArea].Trim()` to `AreaItems[SelectedArea.Trim()]` still doesn't work.

Comment: I strongly suspect that either the `SelectedArea` or `AreaItems` changed between your changes from accessing the dictionary in-line in the string concatenation versus assigning to a temp variable.  How do those variables get populated?

Comment: I have tested your code out of curiosity, it is working fine for me. Are you taking variable `selectedArea` from an input, so that there is a minor spelling change, lower/upper case difference or extra white spaces in middle?

Comment: Use the debugger! It's what it's there for. Break on the line. Inspect. Win.

Comment: @juharr The dictionary is not being changed anywhere else. There is no way, the key could have changed when its showing the key when debugging the line?

Comment: Does getting the `LevelItems[SelectedLevel]` make changes to the `AreaItems`?

Comment: @Lloyd I have, thats how why I am so confused right now, because when I break on that line `AreaItems` has the EXACT same keys and values (as posted above) and the `SelectedArea` is exactly the same string as one of the keys so why the error

Comment: If you could post the chunk of code from initializing dictionary till the line of error, it might help to figure out the issue.

Comment: @J3soon No, not at all.. the `LevelItems` is a public field

Comment: @wonderbell Okay, bare with me

Comment: How about changing the line to `string theWhereClause = " areas = '" + AreaItems[SelectedArea] + "' AND levels = '" + LevelItems[SelectedLevel] + "'";` see if the exception thrown or not.

Comment: @wonderbell Added!

Comment: I still cannot understand the problem with this code, my test code is working fine. The only problem I could think of is "input values". May be function `SearchForWorksheets` got wrong value for parameter `area`. You can try writing unit test and test it with both of your implementations using same input data. Sorry couldn't help much.

Comment: Could you make a full but small (contained, without sql/web) working sample that shows the same results?